# JSON error when requesting a web api

Tags: c#, json, post, surveymonkey

When trying to call the survey list from survey monkey i get the error `{"status": 3, "errmsg": "No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)"}` when using the code below. I'm unsure why this request isn't working and was wondering what im missing or misusing with this post request.

```
 string byteData = "?Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byteData += "&api_key=apikey";
            byte[] clientData = encoding.GetBytes(byteData);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list" + byteData);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + responseToken);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            using (Stream contentStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                contentStream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);
                contentStream.Close();
            }
            HttpWebResponse contentResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string result = new StreamReader(contentResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you told us what the error was?

Comment: oops i totally left that out haha ill edit it

Comment: How about you fire up fiddler and see what is it you are getting back?

Comment: i got 
`RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
~headers~: 107`

Comment: Have you read the [documentations](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/requests_responses)? You are **not** posting *json*.

Comment: @WillS: There is your answer, you are not posting JSON to begin with.

Comment: What should i be posting then? I'm writing in c#. All i see in the documentation is that all requests are done with json. Is json only the return value?

Comment: @WillS please read the documentation (*carefully*). Nothing is correct in your code. `Content-Type`, `Authorization`, `Url`, `body of the request`. all wrong....

Comment: Well this is terrible... ill start over i guess

Comment: I think a lot of your difficulty will go away if you stick to using your server side code to simply get/generate the data and handle the JSON post via JavaScript.